# How to control Jelastic Traffic Distributor via API

Tags: load-balancing, jelastic, blue-green-deployment

Traffic Distributor (https://docs.jelastic.com/traffic-distributor) is a cool feature which add's load balancing to your app and enables Blue/Green deploy.
However, seems that there's no API to control traffic distributor so it's impossible to automate new releases rollout.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to create and control Traffic Distributor via [API](https://docs.jelastic.com/api-overview).

Let us explain the flow...

At first, you should login to the platform and get your session.
This can be done by next API request:

```
https://app.{platform_domain}/1.0/users/authentication/rest/signin/login={your_email}&password={your_password}
```

If you are using Jelastic platform v**5.1+** you should perform the mentioned request as POST.

As example, you can do this using curl:

```
curl 'https://app.{platform_domain}/1.0/users/authentication/rest/signin' -d "login={your_email}&password={your_password}"
```

Next, you can create the Traffic Distributor using this request:

```
http://appstore.{platform_domain}/InstallApp?envName=[env_name]&session=[your_session]&jps=traffic-distributor&displayName=[disp_env_name]&settings={"extip":true,"balancerCount":1,"routingMethod":"round-robin","range":50,"backend1":"{environment_1}","backend2":"{environment_2}"}
```

, where

- **[env_name]** - the name of the environment.
- **[disp_env_name]** - the visible name of the environment in the Dashboard.
- **[your_session]** - your session, which can be taken from the response of the previous request.

The necessary settings of the Traffic Distributor can be specified inside the JSON:

- **extip** - enables the external IP for the Traffic Distributor ( **Highly recommended!** ).
- **balancerCount** - count of the balancers inside the Traffic Distributor. (by default = **1**)
- **routingMethod** - defines the necessary method of the traffic's routing.

You can specify next possible values: **round-robin**, **sticky-sessions** or **failover**

- **range** - define the percent of the traffic, that will be routed to the first environment.

*For example:
**0** - All requests will be routed to the {environment_2},
**100** - All requests will be routed to the {environment_1},
**50** - All requests will be balanced between environments equally.*

- **{environment_1}** - URL to the first environment like env-XXXXXXX.{platform_domain}
- **{environment_2}** - URL to the second environment like env-XXXXXXX.{platform_domain}

After executing this method - Traffic Distributor will appear in the Jelastic Dashboard.

Please, execute next API request to take the "**uniqueName**" value from the response (inside the **Addons** section):

```
https://app.{Platform_domain}/1.0/environment/control/rest/getenvinfo?envname=[env_name]&session=[your_session]
```

, where **[env_name]** - the name of the created environment with the Traffic Distributor addon.

Now you can control the settings of the created Traffic Distributor by next API:

```
https://appstore.{Platform_domain}/ExecuteAppAction?session=[your_session]&appUniqueName=[app_unique_name]&action=configure&params={"extip":1,"balancerCount":1,"routingMethod":"sticky-sessions","range":50,"backend1":"{environment_1}","backend2":"{environment_2}"}
```

, where

**[app_unique_name]** - the value "**uniqueName**" from the response of the previous request.

The settings inside the **JSON** exactly the same as for the **InstallApp** API request.

Comment: Great! Is this mentioned in official docs or you're on the way to update?